# Unsafe use of expression any on header object

Tags: typescript, lint

So i'm having the no-unsafe-any linting error on Typescript when trying to get a custom header from my header variable.

It is defined in this interface:

```
   export interface AxiosResponse<T = any>  {
   data: T;
   status: number;
   statusText: string;
   headers: any;
   config: AxiosRequestConfig;
   request?: any;
}
```

and when trying to get a custom id am getting this error like this:

```
    case HttpStatusCode.SeeOther: {
                const errorMessage: string =
                    (err.response.data as GenericError).message ||
                    err.response.statusText;
                if (err.response.headers.id && event) {
                    apiResponse = ResponseBuilder.seeOther(
                        requestContext,
                        HttpStatusCode.SeeOther,
                        errorMessage,
                        {
                            location: `${event.requestContext.resourcePath}/${err.response.headers.id}`,
                        }
                    );
```

I have tried several ways but i cannot make it work.

ERROR: (no-unsafe-any) utilities.ts[159, 40]: Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'.
ERROR: (no-unsafe-any) utilities.ts[159, 41]: Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`no-unsafe-any`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unsafe-any/) is meant to warn you when you try to access something typed to `any`. You can get around this by correctly typing before using like so:

```js
err.response.headers.id // this will error 
(err.response.headers as unknown as {id: string}).id // this should work
```

Comment: dammmmmn it worked, i wasn't even near to that solution. Thank you George